# display different header text if view has taxonomy term

Tags: views

I have a view which displays different taxonomy terms, I would like to set a different "header text" depending on what term the view is filtering by. Right now whatever header text I choose I can only apply to all pages of the view. [image]I would like to display different header text depending on what term is being filtered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a Global: text area, you should embed another (new) view in the header.

[This blog post](http://sergiy.kyrylkov.name/2012/02/29/showing-taxonomy-description-in-taxonomy-term-view-in-drupal-7/) explains how you can display the term description that way. That way you would have a different text for each term.